# How to dynamically calculate gradient percentage

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I have an array which has dynamic values from server

```
let arr = ['#eee','#fff','#aaa']
or sometimes,
let arr = ['#eee','#fff','#aaa','#eee','#fff','#aaa']
```

Now, I need to calculate the gradient values for equal distribution of colors. I did something like below which is giving some wrong value.

```js
let arr = ['#eee','#fff','#aaa','#eee','#fff','#aaa']

let gper = parseFloat(100/arr.length)

let c_arr = arr.map((k, i) => {  return `${k} ${parseFloat(gper * i--)}% ${parseFloat(gper * i)}%`})
               .toString()
               
console.log(`linear-gradient(to left, ${c_arr})`)
```

Is there a best way to fix this

Comment: Percentage of what?  You're looking for the percentage of value between 0 and 255 for a particular color channel?

Comment: @Brad please refer this for more about linear gradient percentage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()

Comment: @Brad here is an example `background : linear-gradient(red 0%, orange 10% 30%, yellow 50% 70%, green 90% 100%);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want even distribution of colors in your gradient, it is not necessary to specify percentage at all.  The browser does this by default.

You can simply do something like this:

```
`linear-gradient(to left, ${arr.join()})`
```

Comment: Sorry for my English, I don't want colors to be faded. I mean colours should be display as box. like red|yellow|green. the above thing will mix and fade the colours at edges.

Comment: I need this look  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()#gradient_with_multi-position_color_stops

Answer (score 0):

There is just a slight alteration needed to the calculation - in the question the first value went negative.

This snippet spells it out in a loop just to make it a bit clearer - the values need to start at 0 not -gper.

```js
let arr = ['#eee', '#fff', '#aaa', '#eee', '#fff', '#aaa']

let gper = parseFloat(100 / arr.length)

let c_arr = '';
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  c_arr += ((i == 0) ? '' : ', ') + arr[i] + ' ' + i * gper + '%' + ' ' + (i + 1) * gper + '%';
}
console.log(`linear-gradient(to left, ${c_arr})`);
```

The result is:

```
linear-gradient(to left, #eee 0% 16.666666666666668%, #fff 16.666666666666668% 33.333333333333336%, #aaa 33.333333333333336% 50%, #eee 50% 66.66666666666667%, #fff 66.66666666666667% 83.33333333333334%, #aaa 83.33333333333334% 100%)
```